# How can I DynamoDB Table with Partition Key on apply between condition?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-dynamodb

sql query like this:

```
select * from table where Date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-08-18'
           OR
select * from table where Date >= '2020-07-01' AND Date <= '2020-08-18'
```

How can i perform above condition in DynamoDB with partition key.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the partition key (and not a sort key) then you have 2 choices.

You either would use a Scan which supports a [ScanFilter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.ScanFilter.html) of `BETWEEN`, or you would need to perform a query against each partition key individually.

AWS have published an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.PHP.04.html#GettingStarted.PHP.04.Scan) of using Scans in PHP within their documentation.

**Generally** you would try to avoid using Scans as it is very inefficient from a resource point of view and will consume large amounts of `RCU` as it tries to retrieve the result, whereas a Query is more efficient.

This is because a [Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) operation is performed across all partitions with any filters being applied **after** the data has been retrieved, whereas a [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) operation is performed on a single partition with filters applied before data is retrieved.

If this is an issue for you, you could look at remodelling the DynamoDB table to allow the usage of a better partition key and use the data range as a sort key for the table. Alternatively you could create a [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on your table to have a partition key shared by all the data, with the date range used as a sort key. This would allow you to filter the sort key using a query condition.